# New invoice not showing up in ubercart

Tags: templates, drupal, ubercart, invoice

I'll make this quick because I'm hoping to get it fixed as quickly as possible!

Basically, after making multiple posts asking for assistants creating a invoice template for ubercart, non of which got a reply, I decided to tackle my problam myself.

And that's what I've done. I've uploaded it to "/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_order/templates" with the name "uc_order-custom.tpl.php" ( like everyone says on the internet) but when I go to select which template I want to use only 'admin' and 'customer' appear (no 'custom')!

Any idea's why?

---

It appears, now, that the problem is with the dropdown menu's on the pages; the will not updte! Even if I delete the standard customer template from the directory, the option still appears in the menu but the email is just blank, for obvious reasons! So, I just wondered if it was possible for me to manually code/tell ubercart which template to use for the invoice, instead of relaying on the  drop down menu's (if we can't figure out how to update them)?

Thanks in Advance, Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [clearing Drupal's cache](http://drupal.org/node/337176). New template files only get loaded when the template cache is cleared.

Comment: Oh, I really thought that would of worked but I refreshed the page after clearing the cache and still only the two standard templetes! :(

Comment: Okay, that's wired! I've just discovered if I delete the standard customer template, the drop down menu still doesn't update but the email is just blank because there's obviously no template! I've updated my question to append this one: but is it possible to manually select the invoice template instead of relaying on the drop down box?

Comment: What version of Ubercart are you using? Also, did you also copy the original uc_order-customer.tpl.php into your theme directory, as described on the following page? http://www.ubercart.org/docs/developer/17385/changing_invoice_templates_ubercart_23_and_later

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Ubercart (I think) but it's okay now because I got around it by simply replacing the uc-order_customer.tpl.php so it thinks it the standard template still. Although, I didn't do what you (and the link) said so it probably would of worked if I did, but it's working fine for me at the minute so I won't bother trying to do it the "Corect" way! Thank you anyway!

Comment: Just FYI, depending on how you handle updating, there's a good chance your changes will be overwritten when you update to newer versions of Ubercart. You might want to consider the method explained in the link above, to avoid having to redo your changes later.

Answer (score 1):

You need also to copy uc_order.tpl.php to your templates folder.